# Should I use class instance(serialized) or Singleton for storing userInfo once the user login

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c

I want to know what would be a better approach for Storing user info once he logs in. Should I parse the data into Serizaled object class? Or should I create A singleton. Mostly I get around 12-13 obejects from the server once I login, however 2-3 of them are used all over the app, the others are not very common.

Comment: Store that info in the request session so its accessible in any moment for the user again

Comment: What I have done, is storing the whole response in an SharedPrefences, once I open the app, I parse these data if the user isn't null to a serializable class using Gson. and I have already created a base that inherits all classes that has method called getUser and User Obect (the serialzed class) and whenever I need to get user's name, id or whatever. I call in the class getUser().getUserId for instance. Is that a good way?

Comment: Well you could store the full object without the need to serialize/deserialize with Gson, but is not a bad solution

Comment: Aha okay, but won't serializing the data in a class makes it faster to retrieve for eg; 
userId instead of calling the whole response and then getJsonObject(userId) it would be just calling getUserId? and also it would make me have less methods in the base, all userInfo methods would be inside The User Class

Comment: Ah ok i missunderstand you if you store the java object in the session or sharedPreferences is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options. Read here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

In your case perhaps you can simply use SharedPreferences, here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("FILE_NAME",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To put the value:
(.commit() instead of .apply() if you care whether or not putString was successful)

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(COOKIE_SP_FILE_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPreferences != null) {
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("KEY", "VALUE").apply();
    }
```

To retrieve the value:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("FILE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPreferences != null) {
        String theString = sharedPreferences.getString("KEY", "DEFAULT_VALUE");
    }
```

Where "DEFAULT_VALUE" is what you would get if no value with "KEY" as key was found.

Comment: What I have done, is storing the whole response in an SharedPrefences, once I open the app, I parse these data if the user isn't null to a serializable class using Gson. and I have already created a base that inherits all classes that has method called getUser and User Obect (the serialzed class) and whenever I need to get user's name, id or whatever. I call in the class getUser().getUserId for instance. Is that a good way?

Comment: I mean, sure, try to store as little as possible in the app itself, then create a RESTful api, then you would basically only need to store the token. And also, the less info you store, and states that ur app can have, the easier it is to test.